# Send-mailmessage with attachment

Tags: task, powershell-2.0, scheduler

I have a ps1 script which runs conditionally upon an event from Task Scheduler.  The event that triggers my script is another task that finishes and writes "... completed successfully" to the Task Scheduler event log.  When this occurs, my script sends and HTML email (send-mailmessage) with an attached file to specific users.
The problem is that it works when I run it manually but when I set up the condition (still sends the email) but doesn't attach the file!... here's my code:

---

```
$HTML = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE></TITLE>

$Messages
</body></html>
"@


$SMTPServer = "smtp.myserver.com"
$SMTPPort = "1234"
$Username = "xyz@mycompany.com"
$Password = "xyz-password"
$to = "Automation@xxxxx.net"
$bcc = "testuser@xyz.net"
$subject = "My Import Alert"
$attachment = "(unc path to the .csv)-$(get-date -f yyMMdd).csv"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $HTML
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.to.add($to)
$message.bcc.add($bcc)
$message.from = "Import Alerts <Automation@xyz.net>"
$message.attachments.add($attachment)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$SMTPMessage=New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp.send($message)
```

---

So, when it's manually run, it works fine (with attachement)... every time!!
When I have it set to run via task scheduler it works (sends the email) BUT THRE'S NO ATTACHMENT!  IT WAS RUNNING FINE, UNTIL TODAY(!)

I don't know how to debug or test this at all... any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!!!
B-

Comment: You're not using send-mailmessage in your code. In your description, you say that you are.  Is this *really* the script you're running on the schedule?

Comment: Does the user account under which the scheduled task executes have permission to access the UNC path to the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new myself and have only been working with PowerShell for about 7 months now, but I might be able to help. While I generally use the Send-MailMessage -To -From, etc. (have you tried [this](http://ss64.com/ps/send-mailmessage.html)?) method to send emails, I have used the method you show on occasion as well.

From looking at your code and comparing it to what I have, I note that you're missing `$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($emailAttach, $attachmentType)`. I also see that I've made a comment in my script that you need to include `$message.Dispose()` after you send the email or there will be a write lock on the attachment in question.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following two-liner works for me and can be scheduled. Change `gmail-user@gmail` etc. to match your account and credentials:

```
$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “gmail-user@gmail.com”, (“gmail-user's password” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

Send-MailMessage -From "gmail-user@gmail.com" -to "someone-else@gmail.com" -Subject "Some subject"
-Body "Some body" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -port 587 -UseSsl
-Credential $credentials -Attachments "C:\an-attachment.txt"
```